# How to use obtain in existential proofs?

Tags: isabelle, isar

I tried to prove an existential theorem

```
lemma "∃ x. x * (t :: nat) = t"
proof
  obtain y where "y * t = t" by (auto)
```

but I could not finish the proof. So I have the necessary `y` but how can I feed it into the original goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soundness of natural deduction requires that you get hold of the witness before you open the existential quantifier. This is why you are not allowed to use obtained variables in `show` statements. In your example, the `proof` step implicitly applies the rule `exI`. This turns the existentially quantified variable `x` into the schematic variable `?x`, which can be instantiated later, but the instantiation may only refer to variables that have been in scope when `?x` came into place. In the low-level proof state, obtained variables are meta-quantified (`!!`) and the instantiations for `?x` can only refer to such variables that appear as a parameter to `?x`.

Therefore, you have to switch the order in your proof:

```
lemma "∃ x. x * (t :: nat) = t"
proof - (* method - does not change the goal *)
  obtain y where "y * t = t" by (auto)
  then show ?thesis by(rule exI)
qed
```

Comment: You can use `proof` without `-` (which applies the `default` method) if your witness does not mention any obtained variables. I your example, you can use `Suc 0` as the witness rather than obtain it. But I assume that your real use case is more complicated. If you define your witness `y` using `def` from constants instead of using `obtain`, it should work. Alternatively, you can always eliminate obtained variables by using the choice operator `SOME`, but that is cumbersome to write and read.

Comment: I do not have real use case, I wanted to construct an example for using `obtain`.

Answer (score 5):

You can give the witness (i.e. the element you want to put in for x) in the `show` clause:

```
lemma "∃ x. x * (t :: nat) = t"
proof
  show "1*t = t" by simp
qed
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, when you already know the witness (`1` or `Suc 0` here), you can explicitly instantiate the rule `exI` to introduce the existential term:

```
lemma "∃ x. x * (t :: nat) = t"
  by (rule exI[where x = "Suc 0"], simp)
```

Here, the existential quantifier introduction rule `thm exI` is

```
?P ?x ⟹ ∃x. ?P x
```

you can explore and instantiate it gradually with the answer.

`thm exI[where x = "Suc 0"]` is:

```
?P (Suc 0) ⟹ ∃x. ?P x
```

and `exI[where P = "λ x. x * t = t" and x = "Suc 0"]` is

```
Suc 0 * t = t ⟹ ∃x. x * t = t
```

And `Suc 0 * t = t` is only one simplification (`simp`) away. But the system can figure out the last instantiation `P = "λ x. x * t = t"` via unification, so it isn't really necessary.

Related:

[Instantiating theorems in Isabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334282)