# Instantiating theorems in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Suppose some lemma, lets call it `an_equation`, proves that equation f(n)=n*n+1 holds for all odd natural numbers n (and f is some previously defined function).

How can I instantiate this lemma to concrete values of n, so that I can prove, say f(5)=5*5+1?

(There is the `lemmas` keyword, with which I can prove `lemmas inst = an_equation[where n=5, simplified]`, but this is not quite what I what. What I want is

```
lemma inst_new : "f(5) = 5*5+1"
```

but as  there were scarcely any example around in the usual documentation thai I consult, I couldn't figure out how to prove this.)

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate free variables in your theorem with the `of` and `where` attributes, e.g. `an_equation[of 5]` or `an_equation[where n = 5]`. You can also instantiate its assumptions, e.g. if you have a theorem called `foo` of the form `P x ⟹ Q x` and you have a theorem called `bar` of the form `P 5`, you can do `foo[OF bar]` to get the theorem `Q 5`.

You can inspect these instantiated with `thm` (e.g. `thm foo[of 5]`) and use them in a proof with `using`, `from`, etc.

Note that proof methods also instantiate theorems whenever needed, e.g. if you have, as above, the theorem `foo` stating that `P n ⟹ Q n` and you have the goal `Q 5`, you can do this:

```
lemma "Q 5"
  apply (rule foo)
```

Then the goal state will have one subgoal, namely `P 5`.

So, in your case, `by (rule an_equation)` should do the trick. Something like `by (simp add: an_equation)` or `using an_equation by simp` or `using an_equation by blast` would probably also work, but might be slightly less robust in general since the simplifier can do other stuff first and then the rule might not apply anymore.